# Execute a function after two (or more) ajax request succeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to perform two independent ajax requests and a function to be executed after both of them succeed. I can obviously send the first request, then send the second one when the first one succeeds and finally execute the function when the second request succeeds. But is there a way to execute them separately and execute the function when both of them succeed?

i.e. I could have the following requests:

```
var jqxhr1 = $.post( "example1.php", function() {
  alert( "first success" );
})
var jqxhr2 = $.post( "example2.php", function() {
  alert( "second success" );
})
```

and the following function:

```
function myfunction() {
  alert( "function success" );
}
```

Comment: so you don't want to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) ? correct?

Comment: Why cant you have a counter and just increment the counter on success? (if you dont want to have to ajax calls one inside the other of course)

Comment: Could you show us a bit of code, just so we see how you perform your ajax requests (callback, promise etc?)

Comment: @inspired: I never used promise before, so I couldn't tell you if that's the case.

Comment: @giusva can you show us some code? You can do what the other's recommended, but that can be messy. It'll be best to use the power of promises.

Comment: This is what Promises are for.

Comment: @Pogrindis as I said I didn't know their existence. I will try to fill my ignorance and I'll let you know.

Comment: @Pogrindis since it seems that Promise is the best solution, please wrote an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many commented under your question the best way is to use Promises. As I see you are using `jQuery` so I will post you my answer using jQuery. So the basic setup will be:

**html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="one">Send 2 ajax</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**example1.php**:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST['button']);
```

**example2.php**:

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo json_encode($_POST['button']);
```

And `javascript` file:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    var $button1 = $( '#one' );

    $button1.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.when(
            $.ajax( {
                url: "example1.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { button: "some data" }
            } ),
            $.ajax( {
                url: "example2.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { button: "some data" }
            } ) ).done( function ( a1, a2 ) {
            console.log( a1 );
            console.log( a2 );
        } );

    } )

} );
```

**Explanation**: [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is used when you want to wait until several `ajax` request are successful. So in my example **done()** is executed  **after 5 seconds** when two ajax request are successful. First and second params is returned values from first and second ajax call. You can read more about it in link I provided above. Returned data is like this:

```
Array[3]
    0:""Some data from AJAX 1""
    1:"success"
    2:Object
    length:3
    __proto__:Array[0]

Array[3]
    0:""Some data from AJAX 2""
    1:"success"
    2:Object
    length:3
    __proto__:Array[0]
```

**example1.php** and **example2.php** are very simple - they just send `json` back to javascript. Except that **example2.php** simulates ajax response timeout of 5 seconds.

**P.S.**: Code above is working example, which I'm running on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `$.when` In the case where multiple Deferred objects

```
var jqxhr1 = $.post( 'example1.php');
var jqxhr2 = $.post( 'example2.php');

$.when(jqxhr1, jqxhr2).then(function( response1, response2 ) {
   console.log('both requests succeed, do staff here')
});
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable called requestsCompleted and asign it a value of zero. Every time a request is completed, add 1 to the variable, and when its equal to two, execute the function

**Edit:** As @Pogrindis pointed out, the best way is to use Promise.all() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: No, just use Promises they're there for a reason.

Comment: @Pogrindis I didn't know that method, but it's definitely better, I'll change my answer

Comment: They're a rather vital tool in Javascript's asynchronicity, I highly advise you read up on them.

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm a begginer in web development, so I'm learning on the fly. Thanks for the advice, I'll keep do that

Comment: A promise is just a wrapper for asynchronous tasks. Ajax is one such asynchronous task that a promise can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
 var count = 0;

    while (count < 2){
     //do ajax call
         //on success increment counter
         //on error just log and continue

    //you can put a timeout here and just do 'return' after if you wish
    }

    functionCall();
```

Comment: No, just use Promises they're there for a reason.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this way, if one of the two request doesn't succeed there is an infinite loop. And if I put a timeout the code is still stuck in the loop for a while. I mean that in this way I lose the beauty of the asynchronous request.

Comment: Thats why i said you need to catch the error and continue + you can <code> return </code> if it timeouts which would exit the function

Comment: and yes you can use promises im not very familiar with it. Promises or this is not the only way of doing it, this is just a suggestion @Pogrindis

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin no need to re-invent the wheel. Using the right tool for the job usually works.

Comment: its not reinventing the wheel its a basic while loop. There is no need to defend your answer I'm not saying its wrong I'm saying this is also a way of doing it. At the end Promises is doing something similar im pretty sure but its just extracted into a seperate method